# Google signin error in react-native version 0.57.8

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-authentication

I want to implement google authentication in my react-native application but even i have followed the documentation it gives me strange error:

```
RNGoogleSigninPackage.java:25: error: 
 method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
 @Override
 ^
1 error
:react-native-google-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

In IOS it works everything perfect but when i try in windows 10 it gives me the error also i have tried to delete @Override from file RNGoogleSigninPackage.java:25 then the build is successful but the application doesn't start in simulator.

Comment: Have you tried to launch it in a physical device?

Comment: Yes still the same error